# Can not run javaFx jar in chrome

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

i wrote a javaFx app with intellij-idea and built the artifacts. Then i uploaded the generated files to [this link](http://rdroid.info/JavaFX/FileFilter.html) and opened this link in chrome. the page told me that should download java, so i followed the instructions to download java (again), but after i started the page again, the same message appeared. i am using the latest chrome version and windows 8 (64 bit). what am i doing wrong?

this is the generated html i am using:

```
<html><head><SCRIPT src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></SCRIPT>
<script>
function launchApplication(jnlpfile) {
    dtjava.launch(            {
            url : 'FileFilter.jnlp'
        },
        {
            javafx : '8.0+'
        },
        {}
    );
    return false;
}
</script>

<script>
function javafxEmbed_FileFilter_id() {
    dtjava.embed(
        {
            id : 'FileFilter_id',
            url : 'FileFilter.jnlp',
            placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder',
            width : 600,
            height : 400
        },
        {
            javafx : '8.0+'
        },
        {}
    );
}
<!-- Embed FX application into web page once page is loaded -->
dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed_FileFilter_id);
</script>

</head><body>
<h2>Test page for <b>FileFilter</b></h2>
  <b>Webstart:</b> <a href='FileFilter.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication('FileFilter.jnlp');">click to launch this app as webstart</a>     
<br><hr><br>

<!-- Applet will be inserted here -->
<div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>
</body></html>
```

this is my jnlp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="FileFilter.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>FileFilterTest</title>
    <vendor>Unknown vendor</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="FileFilter.jar" size="69241" download="eager" />
    <jar href="commons-io-2.4.jar" size="185140" download="eager" />
</resources>
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="600" height="400" main-class="at.richardlederer.filefilter.MainApp"  name="FileFilter" />
    <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

and this is the screen i get when i open the link

[image]

Comment: Do you have java installed? make sure it's not being blocked by a popup blocker. I checked, worked for me until I got security warning.

Comment: yes sure. i clicked the link telling me to download java and then installed it. and i could not find any pop up blocker message on my page.

Comment: Can you run it outside a browswer? make sure your JRE version matches your JDK and what you target. Also make sure if you are generating 32bit code that you have JRE for 32bit

Comment: yes, the jar runs outside the browser without any problems.

Comment: I would have to say make sure you have the right JRE installed then. JavaFX binaries are included in the JRE, not a seperate thing really.

Comment: i just installed the SDK (1.8.0_51) and developed with the same version as the JRE, but nothing changed.